# Converting Unicode codepoints to UTF-8 in C using iconv

Tags: c, unicode, encoding, utf-8, iconv

I want to convert a 32-bit value, which represents a Unicode codepoint, into a sequence of `char`s which is the utf-8 encoded string containing only the character corresponding to the codepoint.

For example, I want to turn the value `955` into the utf-8 encoded string `"λ"`.

I tried to do this using `iconv`, but I could not get the desired result. Here is the code that I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iconv.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void)
{
  uint32_t codepoint = U'λ';
  char *input = (char *) &codepoint;
  size_t in_size = 2; // lower-case lambda is a 16-bit character (0x3BB = 955)

  char output_buffer[10];
  char *output = output_buffer;
  size_t out_size = 10;

  iconv_t cd = iconv_open("UTF-8", "UTF-32");

  iconv(cd, &input, &in_size, &output, &out_size);

  puts(output_buffer);

  return 0;
}
```

When I run it, only a newline is printed (`puts` automatically prints a newline,-- the first byte of `outout_buffer` is `'\0'`).

What is wrong with my understanding or my implementation?

Comment: Note that the argument order for `iconv_open` is destination encoding, source encoding.

Comment: I know, I was trying something else and forgot to change it back. Thanks for catching that. It still doesn't work, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems:

1. Since you’re using UTF-32, you need to specify 4 bytes. The “lower-case lambda is a 16-bit character (0x3BB = 955)” comment isn’t true for a 4-byte fixed-width encoding; it’s 0x000003bb. Set `size_t in_size = 4;`.
2. iconv doesn’t add null terminators for you; it adjusts the pointers it’s given. You’ll want to add your own before calling `puts`.

   ```
   *output = '\0';
   puts(output_buffer);
   ```

Comment: The call to `iconv` is setting `errno` to `EISEQ`, which according to the man page for `iconv`, means the input sequence was invalid. I've incorporated both of your suggested changes.

Comment: @BradleyGaragan: Does `char codepoint[4];
  codepoint[0] = 0xbb;
  codepoint[1] = 0x03;
  codepoint[2] = 0x00;
  codepoint[3] = 0x00;
  char *input = codepoint;` work?

Comment: @BradleyGaragan: How about if you swap `0` with `3` and `1` with `2`?

Comment: It works! I'm guessing this has to do with endianness? I'm curious as to why `iconv` doesn't take that into account, though.

Comment: @BradleyGaragan: Yep, it appears to! I would have thought the endianness problem would have been on the other side. Anyway, you can specify `UTF-32LE` (or `UTF-32LE`) instead for consistency.

Answer (score 3):

As said by minitech, you must use `size = 4` for UTF32 in an `uint32_t`, and you must preset the buffer to null to have the terminating null after conversion.

This code works on Ubuntu :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iconv.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <memory.h>

int main(void)
{
  uint32_t codepoint = 955;
  char *input = (char *) &codepoint;
  size_t in_size = 4; // lower-case lambda is a 16-bit character (0x3BB = 955)

  char output_buffer[10];
  memset(output_buffer, 0, sizeof(output_buffer));
  char *output = output_buffer;
  size_t out_size = 10;

  iconv_t cd = iconv_open("UTF-8", "UTF-32");

  iconv(cd, &input, &in_size, &output, &out_size);

  puts(output_buffer);

  return 0;
}
```